# Unable to load the package ComplexHeatmap

Tags: r

I am new to R and I installed the package from `Bioconductor` but wasn't able to load the package.

I am using R version 4.1.2 on Mac M1, Mac OS 12

Since I couldn't use `install_github()` to install the package, I did:

```
install.packages("/Users/Downloads/ComplexHeatmap_2.10.0.tgz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
install.packages("/Users/Downloads/IRanges_2.28.0.tgz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
install.packages("/Users/Downloads/S4Vectors_0.33.10.tgz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

And I got this error message:

> Loading required package: grid.
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ComplexHeatmap’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/S4Vectors/libs/S4Vectors.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/S4Vectors/libs/S4Vectors.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/S4Vectors/libs/S4Vectors.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/S4Vectors.so' (no such file)

What can I do?

Comment: Since it is a Bioc package you should follow the directions on its Bioc package description page. It’s not as simple as just issuing an install.packages command.

Comment: Thanks! I just found that the problem is Bioconductor does not support the Apple M1 (a.k.a. arm64) architecture in native mode, I should choose R-4.1.2.pkg,  not R-4.1.2-arm64.pkg.